# Remove CSV fields with no values for large files

Tags: shell-script, scripting

So I made this script which takes in a CSV file as an argument and then gets rid of any fields with less than 2 unique values in it. this is because the data I am working on has 2 values in every field no matter what. It's just the way the Reddit data is it seems.

Basically what I do is loop through every column using cut and then sort every column uniquely and then if that is less than 2 I save that column number. Then I loop through all the column numbers that I noted and created a big cut command to get rid of them.

The problem is that it runs terribly slow on big files.

I'd like to be able to speed it up if at all possible but I am not well versed in the use of more advanced commands. If someone could show me a faster way to achieve this I would be delighted! thanks.

THE CODE:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

#find number of fields
num_items=$(cat $1 | head -n 1 | grep -o , | wc -w)
num_items=$((num_items + 0))


echo "Searching all $num_items columns for redundancy"

cols=()

command="-f"
for ((i = 1; i < $num_items; i++))
do
    num_vals=$(cat $1 | cut -d, -f$i | sort -u | wc -w)
    x=$(($num_vals+0))

    #remove column if it has less than 2 values in its column
    #lt 3 as we want to discard the field name at the top
    if [ $x -lt 3 ]
    then
        cols+=("$i")
    fi
    bit="$i-$i,"
    command="${command}${bit}"
done
command="${command}$num_items-$num_items"
echo ""
for col in "${cols[@]}"; do
    sed_reg="s/$col-$col,//"
    command=$(echo "$command" | sed $sed_reg)
    echo "col $col has been removed"
done

command="cut -d, ${command} $1"

$command > pruned_cols.csv
```

smaller sample data: https://ufile.io/27bm31d6

~70k lines. 
SAMPLE DATA: https://ufile.io/qvglxajr

System: macOS using zsh

Comment: give a little bit of your file and what you want to get. this way, perhaps i or other can help you.

Comment: I included a sample of the file at the bottom of the question. As for what I want is to remove the fields in the CSV that have no values in their column.

Comment: I saw that but with a file with few lines, i think it's better.

Comment: @ctac_ okay added a smaller file with only 100 lines!

Comment: Your title says "no values" while in the text you mention "less than 2 values" and your code actually seems to check for less than 2 *unique* values - which do you really want?

Comment: hum, do you want i pay or register to get your file ? you can post here 5 or 10 lines and what you expect !

Comment: @steeldriver yes sorry its actually because the sample data from reddit has a value in every field no matter what so I need to make it less than 2 to account for that and the field header.

Comment: There are many rows that are empty, FALSE, TRUE, or a combination of those. Should they all disappear?

Comment: @RudiC any columns that are empty should go. any column that is just False values should go and any column that is just True values should go.

Answer (score 0):

See how far this will get you:

```
$ cut --complement -d, -f$(awk -F, '
NR > 1  {for (i=1; i<=NF; i++)  CNT[i, $i]++
        }
END     {for (c in CNT) if (CNT[c] == (NR-1))   {split (c, T, SUBSEP)
                                                 printf "%s%d", DL, T[1]
                                                 DL = ","
                                                }
        }
' /tmp/small_data.csv)  /tmp/small_data.csv
```

given your `cut` version has the `--complement` option. Else invert the printout logics. If your `awk` loses `NR` in the `END` section, keep it in the per-line-processing.

It runs through all the fields in all lines (except header) and counts unique contents. In the `END` section, if `CNT` equals the line count minus header (i.e. that field has the same contents in all lines), split the index and print the field number.